# Append dictionary to pandas dataframe in callback

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have **callback** method that will create python `dictionary` in loop and append those dictionaries to the `pandas` dataframe,

```
def process_data(self, _data, ec_search, ec_helpers, _log):
    _data_dict = {}
    for single_data in _data:
        _id = single_data.get('id')
        latlon = single_data.get('latlon')
        country_code = single_data.get('country_code')
        _data_dict[property_id] = {'latlon': latlon,'country_code':country_code}

    output = pd.DataFrame() # what to do here?
    output = output.append(_data_dict, ignore_index=True)
    print(output.head())
```

The problem is when I **invoke** this callback from another python **def** it will create the pandas data frame and append the dictionary as rows, but when I invoke second or further than it will re-initialize the `output = pd.DataFrame()` and append the dictionaries. So I just want to make my existing data frame intact while appending the dictionaries, I have seen a similar kind of solution using `pd.concate` but not sure is it the proper way to do it or will it create any performance issue because I've to process around 10M dataset?

Comment: Since it seems you are tracking states, creating a class probably helps.

Comment: basically the idea is I need to append this dictionary on my existing csv file

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `global` keyword to get the dataframe and builtin a check if it already exists or not? Or initiate an empty df as a global variable at the beginning of your program. Either way, if you want to preserve state, then you need to safe the dataframe outside of your function.

Example:

```
x = int(1)

def some_function():
    global x
    for i in range(1, 10):
        x += 1

some_function()
print(x)
```

This will output `10` as variable `x` is stored outside of the method and declared inside the method with `global`.

Comment: I was also thinking about using `global` flag to track state.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class:

```py
class Output(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.Datarame()
        
    def append(self, _data_dict, ignore_index):
        self.data = self.data.append(_data_dict, ignore_index)
```

Now, this should work:

```py
output = Output()
output.append(_data_dict, ignore_index=True) ## call it how ever many times you want!

print(output.data.head())
```